# HTML - Navigate to page, then call function on that page

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, href

In the menu bar, I would like to navigate to a page (draft.php) and call a function Draft_ORI() on that page.

```
<a onclick="location.href='http://example.com/draft.php'; Draft_ORI()">
```

It's a little bit tricky, because Draft_ORI() only exists at the bottom of the destination page.

Comment: Why not set the function to automatically trigger when draft.php is loaded?

Comment: Either have the function called right away by the PHP when it is loaded, or use JavaScript to call it once the DOM is ready

Comment: There are several different functions Draft_ORI(), Draft_DTK(), Draft_ABC() that can be called on the draft page. I'd like the user to specify which of these is loaded on pageload through the dropdown menu

Comment: Is Draft_ORI a PHP or JavaScript function? Either way, to pass the information that you want to call a specific function in the target page you can use a query parameter, e.g. http://example.com/draft.php?functionToCall=Draft_ORI, and then use that on the target page to know which function to call.

Comment: First time hearing about query parameters. Yes that is the way to go. I think I can take it from here, thanks!

Draft_ORI() is a javascript function (by the way).

Answer (score 0):

Your link should look like this

```
<a href="draft.php?a=Draft_ORI"/>
```

In your draft.php file

```
<?php

$function = $_GET["a"];

$function();

?>
```

If you pass `?a="something"` the function `something()` will get called.

Does this help?

Comment: There are several different functions similar to Draft_ORI(). I would like to be able to call those instead of Draft_ORI() depending on which option the user selects in a drop down menu on another page.

Comment: Oh, okay let me ammend my answer.

Comment: It's giving the error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function Draft_ORI() in /home/drafts8/public_html/draft.php on line 750

Could this be because Draft_ORI() is a javascript function?

Comment: Yeah well that's quite important information that you didn't provide.. yes that's exactly why.